# char* size is different than expected after malloc

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, memory, char

I've created the next code to obtain a **char***, but after executing this code the size of finalResult is bigger than expected, with some garbage characters. Why?? How can I resolve it?

```
//returns void
void processChar(){
            //.... more stuff here
            // init is a previous char*
            char* end = strstr(init,"</div>");
            if(end != NULL){
                    long length = strlen(init) - strlen(end);
                    if (length > 0){
                            char* finalResult = malloc(length);
                            strncat(finalResult, init,length);
                            //these lengths are different,being strlen(finalResult) > length
                            NSLog(@"%d %d",strlen(finalResult),length);
                            //... more stuff here  
                    }
            }
            return;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code:

```
char* finalResult = malloc(length);
strncat(finalResult, init,length);
```

Will give you an undefined result. You're trying to concatenate `finalResult` with `init`, even though you never initialized `finalResult`. Perhaps you meant to use `strncpy()` instead of `strncat()`?

Also, `finalResult` is not big enough; it needs to also hold the terminating `\0` character, so you should allocate it with:

```
char* finalResult = malloc(length + 1);
```

Furthermore, as pointed out by Keith Thomson, beware of the [dangers of `strncpy()`](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.gr/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html) when you're using it.

In this particular case, you can avoid using `strncpy()` by simply initializing `finalResult` as an empty string after you allocate it, and then use `strncat()` as you did before:

```
char* finalResult = malloc(length + 1);
finalResult[0] = '\0';
strncat(finalResult, init, length);
```

Of course you should also check the return value of `malloc()` for out-of-memory errors, but this is outside the scope of your question.

Comment: Agreed. Or at least initialize `finalResult` to an empty string. e.g.: `finalResult[0] = '\0';`

Comment: And `malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char))`.

Comment: You very probably [don't want to use strncpy()](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: @FlávioToribio: Or just `malloc(length + 1)`; `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: Agree with @Keith here, `strncpy` is useless here since you already _know_ you have enough space (once you `+1` in the `malloc` of course). `strncpy` in general is dangerous in other ways, inasmuch as it doesn't always give you a C string, but that's irrelevant here as well, for the same reason as above. And I changed "random" to "undefined" since I'm feeling particularly pedantic today :-) But +1 anyway since the essence of the answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

From man strlen:

```
The strlen() function calculates the length of the string s, not including the terminating '\0' character.
```

Obviously your malloc will need to allocate space for the terminating '\0' character. So the fix is simple. Allocate length+1 bytes in malloc.

There is a second grave mistake in your code. Malloc will return uninitialized memory, but strncat will append to the existing string. It will therefore first search for the first '\0' in the uninitialized memory which is not what you want. So strncat effectively depends on the first byte of whatever malloc returns being '\0'. You want to use strncpy instead.

Code with the bugs fixed :

```
char * end = strstr(init, "</div>");
if (end != NULL) {
    long length = strlen(init) - strlen(end);
    if (length > 0) {
        char * finalResult = malloc(length+1);
        strncpy(finalResult, init, length);
        printf("strlen(finalResult) = %ld, length = %ld\n", strlen(finalResult), length);
        free(finalResult);
    }
}
```